# How to Perform Window Partitioning with Conditions (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, database-partitioning

I need to know how to narrow down my partitioning window with a condition. For instance, if I have the following:

```
SELECT
  T1.*,
  COUNT(T1.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
FROM TBL T1
WHERE /* some other conditions */;
```

I need the ID partition to only be a subset of all the identical ID's that have `T1.TYPE = 'J'`.

```
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| ID      | TYPE   | OTH1          | OTH2   |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
| 1       | K      | 500           | RER    |
| 1       | J      | 503           | LEL    |
| 1       | J      | 534           | KEL    |
| 2       | J      | 536           | NULL   |
| 2       | J      | 667           | ERT    |
| 2       | J      | 98            | NULL   |
+---------+--------+---------------+--------+
```

In this data set, I need to only consider my window count if `TYPE = J`, so for `ID = 1`, the count should be 2 rather than 3 since the first row is `TYPE = K` (`ID = 2` where the count is 3).

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps conditional aggregation is what you want here:

```
SELECT
      t.*,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'J' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) cnt
FROM TBL t
```

If you only wanted to display this count for those records actually having the `J` type, then we could try:

```
SELECT
      t.*,
      CASE WHEN TYPE = 'J'
           THEN COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'J' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
           ELSE 0 END cnt
FROM TBL t
```

Comment: That does the job. Thanks.